# Не добавляются данные в лид Битрикс24 php API

Tags: php, битрикс24

Первый опыт работы с битрикс24. **Не пинайтесь**.

Создал входящий вебхук. Данные отправляю так, данные, переменные - все верно, так как в телеграм дублируется уведомление о новом лиде и туда все приходит.

```
$bitrixWebhook = 'https://xxxxxxx.bitrix24.ru/rest/1/xxxxxxxxxxx/';
$bitrixQuery = $bitrixWebhook.'crm.lead.add.json';

$bitrixFields = [
'fields' => [
// "STATUS_ID" => '',
"TITLE" => $subject,
"NAME" => $_POST['name'],
"PHONE" => [
"n0" => [
"VALUE" => $_POST['tell'], 
"VALUE_TYPE" => "WORK"
]
],
"COMMENTS" => 'Тест с сайта',
],
'params' => array("REGISTER_SONET_EVENT" => "Y")
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($bitrixFields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $bitrixQuery);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$outs = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($outs, true);
```

В итоге:
лид создается, но название лида, имя и телефон не подтягиваются.

Вопросы:

1. что нужно сделать чтобы приходили название лида, имя и телефон
2. как добавлять лид в другой статус воронки? Сейчас добавляется в первый статус, как узнать *STATUS_ID*? В dev tools id статуса не нашел, там только названия статусов - NEW, IN_PROGRESS.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл отправить заголовки:

```
$headers_json = [
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/json',
];

....
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_json);
```